# Storing data in an array on the basis of a flag

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am working on a angular application. I have one array and in it I have one flag "checked". I need to do some manipulation
on the basis of this flag. My sample data is as follows:

```
 const data = [{
    "checked": true,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName2"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName3"
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myNamePart2"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName2"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName3"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "checked": false,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName4"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName5"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName6"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }, {

    "checked": true,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName7"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName8"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName9"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {

    "checked": true,
     "data": {
          "name": "myName10"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName11"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName12"
            }
          }
        }
  },
  {

    "checked": false,
     "data": {
          "name": "myName13"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName14"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName15"
            }
          }
        }
  }
];
```

In this array, if for any index if "checked" is true, then I want to check the "checked" flag for each children. If for any children, if "checked" flag is
true, then I want to have data from parent name to children name separated by "/" in an array. For above data my final array will have

```
result = ["myName3/myName2/myName","myName3/myName2/myNamePart2","myName9/myName8/myName7","myName12/myName11/myName10"]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What if data.children is false? What you expected to do with nodes where checked is false, but data checked is true? Is level of nesting parents fixed or can be any?

Comment: children can have only one parent as shown in my sample data. If checked is false at first place, then we don't need to do anything. If checked if true for any index, then we check for children array and for each checked - "true" children we need to make path separated by slash as shown in my result array and put it in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a pretty short recursive solution to your problem:

```js
const data = [{
    "checked": true,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName2"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName3"
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myNamePart2"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName2"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName3"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "checked": false,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName4"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName5"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName6"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }, {

    "checked": true,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName7"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName8"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName9"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }, {

    "checked": true,
    "data": {
      "name": "myName10"
    },
    "parent": {
      "data": {
        "name": "myName11"
      },
      "parent": {
        "data": {
          "name": "myName12"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {

    "checked": false,
    "data": {
      "name": "myName13"
    },
    "parent": {
      "data": {
        "name": "myName14"
      },
      "parent": {
        "data": {
          "name": "myName15"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];


const compute = data =>
  data
    .flatMap(x => x.checked && x.children)
    .concat(data)
    .filter(x => x && x.checked && x.data)
    .map(x => createPath(x))
    .map(x => x.join("/"));

const createPath = (node, currentPath = []) =>
  node.parent
    ? createPath(node.parent, [node.data.name, ...currentPath])
    : [node.data.name, ...currentPath];

console.log(compute(data));
```

Comment: I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

Comment: That means your actual input is not the same as in your question

Comment: Wild guess: you have some data without children? If so, try my edited answer

Comment: your guess is correct there was a case when some data is without childrenn. I tested your updated code in that scenario, it is giving me empty array. data with slash is not comin

Comment: There must be some difference between your question sample and your actual data. Hard to guess what.

Comment: wait updating data with no children scenario

Comment: I have updated the data and expected result. Could you please have a look

Comment: I copied it to my answer and it still works perfectly

Comment: I cannot see ""myName12/myName11/myName10"" in your answer

Comment: For me also it is not giving any error but for this type of scenario it is giving me empty array like for you it is not printing "myName12/myName11/myName10" in result array

Comment: Hi Your code is working fine. I just want to know for one scenrios if you can update your code. if parent is null(that means we have reached the end of heirarchy) &  for that node whose parent is null and checked is true, then I want to have the parent in array rather then path with slash and children. For example  for "myName9" one point will come when parent will be null and checked will be true then I need to have only "myName9" in array instead of "myName9/myName8/myName7". Rest other scenrios should work as is they are working now. Could you please add this code

Comment: That will be very helpful. Please don't change this answer just add additional below this code. Thanks

Comment: Hi Guerric, your solution worked for me. But I have a little modification of data today and asked new question including your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592755/store-data-on-the-basis-of-id-and-flag. Request you to please have a look at it and provide a solution for it by doing some modifications to your code

Comment: hey Guerric could you please let me know you updating your answer on my new post?

Comment: Hi Guerric, I have asked my question in a better way now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602847/filtering-data-on-the-basis-of-condition please have a look and help me

Comment: also I request you to please explain your code. I find difficult to understand  const compute = data =>
  data
    .flatMap(x => x.checked && x.children)
    .concat(data)
    .filter(x => x && x.checked && x.data)
    .map(x => createPath(x))
    .map(x => x.join("/"));\\