# Filtering data on the basis of condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on an angular application. My data is as follows.

```
const data = [{
    "checked": true,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName"
        },
        "parent": {
          "checked":true,
          "data": {
            "name": "myName2"
          },
          "parent": {
             "checked":true,
            "data": {
              "name": "myName3"
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myNamePart2"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName2"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName3"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "checked": false,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName4"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName5"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName6"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }, {

    "checked": true,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName7"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName8"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName9"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {

    "checked": true,
     "data": {
          "name": "myName10"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName11"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName12"
            }
          }
        }
  },
  {

    "checked": false,
     "data": {
          "name": "myName13"
        },
        "parent": {
          "data": {
            "name": "myName14"
          },
          "parent": {
            "data": {
              "name": "myName15"
            }
          }
        }
  }
];
```

My expected output is :
In this array, if for any index if "checked" is true, then I want to check the "checked" flag for each child. If for any children, if the "checked" flag is true, then I want to have data from parent name to children name separated by "/" in an array. For the above data, my final array will have.

```
[
  "myName3/myName2/myName",
  "myName3/myName2/myNamePart2",
  "myName9/myName8/myName7",
  "myName12/myName11/myName10"
]
```

My code is as follows which gives me correct output

```
const compute = data =>
  data
    .flatMap(x => x.checked || x.children)
    .concat(data)
    .filter(x => x && x.checked && x.data)
    .map(x => createPath(x))
    .map(x => x.join("/"));

const createPath = (node, currentPath = []) =>
  node.parent
    ? createPath(node.parent, [node.data.name, ...currentPath])
    : [node.data.name, ...currentPath];
```

In this solution, I just want to add one more condition which is as follows:

- If the "checked" flag is true from child to parent, then in my result array I want to have the only parent.
  For example, in my data above I have a node with children and parent as follows

  ```
  "checked": true,
    "children": [{
        "checked": true,
        "data": {
          "name": "myName"
        },
        "parent": {
          "checked":true,
          "data": {
            "name": "myName2"
          },
          "parent": {
             "checked":true,
            "data": {
              "name": "myName3"
            }
          }
        }
      }
  ```

In this, all the "checked" flags from parent-child to parent or we can say from parent to child are true. Then in this case I want to have my output for this in the result array as follows:

```
[
  "myName3",
  "myName3/myName2/myNamePart2",
  "myName9/myName8/myName7",
  "myName12/myName11/myName10"
]
```

Only having "myName3" as all checked flag is true from child to parent. In case if "checked" true is not for child or parent then my code should work as it is working now. How I can do this?

Comment: I honestly don't recommend to handle this case within this step. Imagine programs which know such states. They usually have checkboxes, that are either empty/checked OR have this filled square in case children differ. And that is what I would recommend here. Remove the boolean, which only can serve 2 states, get 3 states and update parents state on state change.

Comment: yes I know but I cannot see anyother way to handle this

Comment: Maybe some kind of recursive approach, which has a return value including  a "allChecked" property you can use.